Problems with log4j2 RollingFile Appender
I'm trying to configure correctly log4j2 but it's not working properly.
I want to create a RollingFile appender that create 10 historic log files and the current log file all with 10MB max size. But now with my appender only create the current log file and the log file with the number 10 contat.
What I'm doing wrong? This is my RollingFile appender declaration
<RollingFile name="F1" fileName="${logPath}/myApp.log" filepattern="${logPath}/myApp.log.%i" append="true" >
    <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="ERROR" maxLevel="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5L %-5p %c{2} %M - %m%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10">
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}">
            <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="10" />
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>

Thanks, regards.


Why your log is written in ${logPath} and deleted will be in ${baseDir} ? 2) You don't need  block.  is enough.


I will try this, thaks!

@WladimirDiskowski I try your solution deleting all the  block with the same issue. When the must be change to the new one and create one historic new, the new one it's named myApp.log.10 I want that when the actual log change to an a historic log be myApp.log.1 not the myApp.log.10

You also want to set fileIndex="min" on the rollover strategy (cf. documentation).

@PiotrP.Karwasz thanks! This was the key. Works perfect.
